# How to link two lambda functions from API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, backend, aws-api-gateway

I have two lambda functions

Lambda 1:

```
def save_events(event):
result = []
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, 
db=db_name,connect_timeout=30)
with conn.cursor() as cur:
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM bodyparts")
for row in cur:
result.append(list(row))
cur.close()
bodyparts = json.dumps(result)
bodyParts=(bodyparts.replace("\"", "'"))
def lambda_handler(event, context):
save_events(event)
return bodyParts
```

Lambda 2:

```
def save_events(event):
result = []
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=, passwd=, db=, connect_timeout=30)
with conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cur:
cur.execute("select exid,exercise_name,image from exercise where bid = 3")
result = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
print ("Data from RDS...")
print (result)
workout = json.dumps(result)
workouts=(workout.replace("\"", "'"))
def lambda_handler(event, context):
save_events(event)
return workouts
```

After the successful execution of lambda 1 it will return list as a json object to the browser using API gateway and now how to invoke the lambda 2 function in API gateway based on the user selection from the output of lambda1 function. 
In lambda2 how to pass user selected item as "bid" value in query.
I know the theory part, really stuck with the implementation part as am a beginner to backend development, Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good option for you is AWS Step Function. If you use Step Functions you can have 2 states with a lambda in each state, the state 1 execute your lambda 1 and pass the result to the second state and execute in it lambda 2. Remember that Step Functions can be called from API Gateway so if you are using API Gateway like endpoint you only need to change the target to Step Functions instead the lambda function. A good way to create all this resources is SAM (Serverless Application Model), using swagger.